# how to compare two dict with values in python

Tags: python-2.7

INPUT :

dict1 = {'hi' : 45, 'thanks' : 34, 'please' : 60}

dict2 = {'hi' : 40, 'thanks' : 46}

OUTPUT:

DIC = {'hi' : 5, 'thanks' : -12, 'please' : 60}

how ? plz give me answer...

Comment: Please explain more. Give an explanation of the problem you are trying to solve. Give examples like what should happen in this case: `input {'a': 34}, {'a': 54, 'b': 10}` ?

Answer (score 0):

So, for each key of dict1 you want :

- if key is also in dict2: `dict1[key] - dict2[key]`
- if key is not in dict2: `dict1[key]`

Am I right?

**Solution:** using a `for` loop

```
dict1 = {'hi' : 45, 'thanks' : 34, 'please' : 60}
dict2 = {'hi' : 40, 'thanks' : 46}
output_dict = {}
for key in dict1.keys() :
    if key in dict2.keys() :
        output_dict[key] = dict1[key] - dict2[key]
    else :
        output_dict[key] = dict1[key]
```

Comment: Your solution won't work for inputs like this:

`dict1 = {'hi' : 40, 'thanks' : 46}`
`dict2 = {'hi' : 45, 'thanks' : 34, 'please' : 60}`